# converting character from mongolite to timestamp in R

Tags: r, timestamp, mongolite

I have a question. I am downloading some data from mongodb and then I want to do sam calculations of this data. Unfortunately I get timestamp as a string I and don't know how to convert it back to timestamp.

```
MaxDate <- con_string$find(query = '{}', sort = '{"timestamp":-1}', limit = 1)$timestamp
```

Above code returns to me maximum date from column timestamp. But format of that is for me totally useful.

```
"Aug 14 2019  8:57AM"
```

Any ideas how to convert it to interpretable by R version of timestamp?

Update:

I[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good link on how to modify strings to dates:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-format-a-string-containing-a-date-into-r-date-object/

It has multiple formats you might want to compare with. For your specific example, I think this should work:

```
MaxDate <- as.Date(MaxDate, "%b %d %Y")
```

if you want to save the Date part only. If you also want to use the time, there is another method you could use for that:

```
strptime(temp, format="%b %d %Y %H:%M%p")
```

More information about `as.Date()` and formats you can find here: [as.Date() helper](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

More information about strptime (date + time) you can find here: [striptime helper](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)

**UPDATE:** I found that package in R that might be helpful for you to avoid multiple conversions: [timestamp conversions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bReeze/versions/0.4-3/topics/timestamp)
You can cast the timestamp data to the measurable time stamp.

Comment: Unfortunately I got NA in both situations. Picture in main post.

Comment: It's probably because the "Aug 14 2019  8:57AM" string you showed is actually not a string but another type.
Could you please tell me what typeof(MaxDate) is?

Comment: It is character. Even if I paste string into your code I got NA.
strptime("Aug 14 2019 8:57AM" ,format="%b %d %Y %H:%M%p")

Comment: That is weird that it's showing NA for you. I tried several online R compilers ([this](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) and [this](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler)) and both of them worked fine. Are you sure your R, RStudio and all packages are up to date?

Comment: #tomsu, check it out over here - it's a working online compiler. If it doesn't work on your computer, I would first recommend updating R itself, RStudio (if you are using it) and other packages through built-in update tools. Sometimes restarting the computer or reinstalling the IDE would help. Here is a code snippet I created with the working code: https://repl.it/repls/AliceblueQuarrelsomeProducts

Comment: You are right, I tried on my private computer and it works. I have to make updates of packages etc on my business one. Thanks men!

Comment: How from Sys.time() get format "Aug 20 2019 7:21AM"?

Comment: @tomsu, I appreciate your question and here is the answer:

`dat <- format(Sys.time(),"%b %d %Y %I:%M%p")`

However, I would recommend googling it first because I found this answer by googling "change date format r" and followed the first [this link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/)